# Contents of ls appearing in middle of output

Tags: bash

I am encountering a very weird situation when wrapping a bash script call in echo $(). This is strange enough that I don't know what code to present, so I will describe the general situation. I have a script, which we will call "run.sh", and it has some output. This is generally formatted quite nicely, with whitespace and line breaks.

I am trying to compare this output with a value that I got when I ran it once previously. To do this, the code compares the "new" value with the old by checking if these two are the same, i.e.:

```
expression=$(./runProcess.sh "$process");
expected=$(cat UnitTests/expect-process-$process);
if [ "$expression" == "$expected" ]; then
```

Clearly to get a value of "old" to compare with future testings I need to compute `$(./runProcess.sh)` by hand. When I do this, I get a version of the output with significantly less whitespace. However it is clearly wrong, because the contents of `ls` turn up in the middle of it. By that I mean that I get the following type of output running these two commands:

```
./runProcess.sh g,g:

R2With2Gluons =

    + ncol*i_*pi_^2*A*g^2 * (
       - 17/24*d_(mu1,mu2)*d_(m1,m2)*p1.p1
       - 31/8*d_(mu1,mu2)*d_(m1,m2)*p1.p2
       - 17/24*d_(mu1,mu2)*d_(m1,m2)*p2.p2
       + 7/12*d_(m1,m2)*p1(mu1)*p1(mu2)
       + 1/24*d_(m1,m2)*p1(mu1)*p2(mu2)
       + 89/24*d_(m1,m2)*p1(mu2)*p2(mu1)
       + 7/12*d_(m1,m2)*p2(mu1)*p2(mu2)
       );

 0.01 sec out of 0.01 sec


echo $(./runProcess.sh g,g):
R2With3Gluons = + coeff(m1,m2,m3)*ncol*pi_^2*A*g^3 Auto Diagrams UnitTests colourCalc.frm form.set functions.frm output.frm process.frm process.mid qgraf2form.frm qgrafProcessor.py runProcess.sh runProcesses.sh test vertices.frm ( + 35/24*d_(mu1,mu2)*p1(mu3) - 35/24*d_(mu1,mu2)*p2(mu3) - 35/24*d_(mu1,mu3)*p1(mu2) + 35/24*d_(mu1,mu3)*p3(mu2) + 35/24*d_(mu2,mu3)*p2(mu1) - 35/24*d_(mu2,mu3)*p3(mu1) ); 0.40 sec out of 0.40 sec
```

And here is ls:

```
ls:
Auto              form.set          process.mid       runProcesses.sh
Diagrams          functions.frm     qgraf2form.frm    test
UnitTests         output.frm        qgrafProcessor.py vertices.frm
colourCalc.frm    process.frm       runProcess.sh
```

I can provide exact examples if necessary, but I hope this is illuminating enough. Why could this possibly be happening? I'm using bash on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Yes, you should provide exact examples.

Comment: "contents of ls"?  Sure you don't have an `*` floating in there?

Comment: Are you storing the output in an environment variable, or is `old` something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right cdarke...

Comment: You need to post your script, not the outputs =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more quotes!!!

Try:

```
echo "$(./run.sh)"
```

instead. (Yes, with quotes).

Try:

```
old=$(./run.sh)
echo "$old"
```

you'll have the correct output (with `$old` in quotes). Now, regarding your test, use, as advised by sampson-chen:

```
[[ "$old" == "$(./run.sh)" ]]
```

(you don't need to quote the variables or the command substitution when assigning the variable `old`, but, as a general rule, you can use quotes **every time**). ((see Gordon Davisson's excellent comments to this post, that I've actually upvoted, with a few caveats about globs and quoting variables inside `[[ ... ]]`)).

**Edit.** As you've edited your post, I see you're using an inefficient `cat`. Instead of:

```
expected=$(cat UnitTests/expect-process-$process)
```

please use

```
expected=$(< "UnitTests/expect-process-$process")
```

Comment: Yep, this is it. Bash is expanding one of the * in my output to the contents of the folder. With quotes, it does not do this!

Comment: Quotes are *usually* not needed inside `[[ ... ]]`, but sometimes they matter -- for example, the `==` operator will treat the right operand as a pattern if it isn't quoted (i.e. `[[ fred == f*d ]]` is true, but `[[ fred == "f*d" ]]` is not). I really recommend getting in the habit of double-quoting *everything* unless there's a reason not to, instead of trying to keep track of all of the cases where it's safe to leave them off.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I was talking about quoting variables and command substitutions, I thought it was clear, since usually people forget to quote their variables. I'll try to make my remark clearer regarding this point, but I will **not** quote the variables and command substitutions in the conditional construct `[[ ... ]]` or in the assignments. Sorry.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: In most cases you can get away with that, but this isn't one of them. `[[ $old == $(./run.sh) ]]` is *wrong* because it's doing a pattern match rather than a simple string compare. For example, if `$old` contained `17/24*d_(mu1,mu2)*d_(m1,m2)*p1.p1` but the similar part of `$(./run.sh)` was only `17/24*p1.p1`, your version would think they match.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Damned, you are **so** right! will edit the post, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without your exact script, but for starters, your comparison:

```
old == $(./run.sh);
```

should be:

```
if [[ "$old" == "$(./run.sh)" ]]; then
```

Comment: This isn't the actual comparison, just there to give you an idiot of the context. I will switch in the actual code into the post.